# There is already an object named 'Roles' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I try to execute my TSQL code, I get the exception:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'Role' in the database.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2
There is already an object named 'User' in the database.
```

But I don't have any database. I need advice.

Code is shown below:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE PortalDB
GO

CREATE TABLE [Role]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [User]
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Role](ID)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not saying there's a table, it's saying there's an object, you've picked two reserved words as table names, which isn't ideal, but moreso they are names of existing objects.  You should choose other names.

Technically you could create a user table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[user]
```

But you should just not use reserved words as table names.  Also, make sure you're using the correct database when you create a table. After the create database you can use:

```
USE PortalDB
GO
```

Or you could specify in the `CREATE TABLE` like:

```
CREATE TABLE PortalDB.dbo.[tablename]
```

Comment: I changed table name but still same exception. I tried too many word.

Comment: I executed 
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.objects
Mssql server created my all table name in sys.objects. Whats wrong i dont understand.

Comment: Tried CREATE TABLE dbo.[user] still same exception.

Comment: Also tried  CREATE TABLE dbo.[asdfasdfsadfsadf] but same exception

Comment: Sorry, was slow in filling out the rest of my answer, make sure you're using the right db, see update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. Thanks to you. Working sql code is shown below:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE FancyDB
GO

    CREATE TABLE FancyDB..[Role]
    (
        [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    )
GO

    CREATE TABLE FancyDB..[User]
    (
        [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        [UserName] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        [Password] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
        [Email] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
        [RoleID] INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Role](ID)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating the objects in Master? It is a system DB.

Comment: Thank you realized that.